# Spring Boot : lazy fetch not working for getById()

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my spring application , Lazy fetch is not working which is making fetch operation from db heavy. So,
when I fetch students using getStudentByRollNo() It is fetching fields EAGERLY which are even marked as Lazy. but when I am using findBySimpleNaturalId() it is loading lazy.

My classes are

Student.class

```
 @Entity
 @Builder
 @ToString
 @Getter
 @Setter
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
class Student{
   @Id
   Long id;
  
   @NaturalId
   String rollNo;
   
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "tutor_fk", nullable = false)
   
   Tutor tutor;
   
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = Courses.student, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   Set<Courses> courses = new HashSet<>();
  
  }
```

Courses.class

```
   @Entity
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @Builder
   @ToString
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
  class Courses{
  Long id;
  String create_date_time;
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "student_fk")
  Student student;
 }
```

Tutor.class

```
   @Entity
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @Builder
   @ToString
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
  class Tutor{
  Long id;
  String name;
}
```

studentService.class

```
 @Transactional
class studentService{
Students getStudent(String rollNo ){
  return studentRepository.findOneByRollNO(rollNo);
} }
```

when I run my code on **org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG**.
querys hit are

```
 select course0_.id as id1_43_0_, course0_.create_date_time as create_date_time2_43_0_ 
  from course course0_ where course0_.id=?
 select tutor0_.id as id1_43_0_, tutor0_.name as name2_43_0_ 
  from tutor tutor0_ where tutor0_.id=?
```

it is hitting above query as eager when these fields are marked LAZY

But when I am running getByNaturalId it is fetching  lazy

```
@Transactional
class studentService{
Students getStudent(String rollNo){
   Map<String, Object> filter = new HashMap<>();
    filter.put("rollNo",rollNo);
  return studentRepository.findBySimpleNaturalId(rollNo);
} }
```

I want to know why is it fetching eager for getByRollNo() and fetching lazy for findBySimpleNaturalId() ?

Comment: Are you sure studentRepository.findOneByRollNO return a student list ?  
Same question for findOneByaturalId.. 
This methods should return a student (not a  list of student as you assume in your service class. 

I Suggest you provide a working snippet so we could answer your question

Comment: I am Sorry. I have edited my mistake. Can you tell reason for this ? @soung

Comment: do you call studentRepository.save(aStudent) before calling select methods? 
Depending on your entities relationship or maybe  manually setting  ids on your entities, hibernate will call select before save. So make sur in your log the  `select courses ...` query is not the result of save